# Event log message size 31885? Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-event-log

We recently upgraded our production boxes to Windows 2008 from Windows 2003 servers. Everything works fine except the event logging. We log at max 32000 bytes of data for each message On 2008 servers, event logging fails if number of characters is greater than 31885. Is this new limit on Windows 2008 R2 servers?
Any help appreciated.
On Win 2003 servers, I am able to log 32000 bytes of data for each log entry.

Comment: Interesting question!  Seems like something would have changed with the other changes to the event log, but the max log item size is a fairly obscure edge case - 32 kilobytes is a whole lot of data for a single log entry!

Answer (score 3):

Old question but there is still no answer.
The size of the log was changed from: 32,766 bytes To: 31,839 bytes
for operation system vista and above.

See here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w20x90k.aspx